# PL/pgSQL trigger table entry limit

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to get an opinion on a trigger I've written for a `PostGreSQL` Database in `PL/pgSQL`. I haven't done it previously and would like to get suggestions by more experienced users.

Task is simple enough:

Reduce the number of entries in a table to a set amount.

What should happen:

- An `INSERT` into to the table device_position occurs,
- If the amount of entries with a specific column (deviceid) value exceeds 50 delete the oldest.
- Repeat

Please let me know if you see any obvious flaws:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trim_device_positions() RETURNS trigger AS $trim_device_positions$
DECLARE
    devicePositionCount int;
    maxDevicePos CONSTANT int=50;
    aDeviceId device_position.id%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO devicePositionCount FROM device_position WHERE device_position.deviceid=NEW.deviceid;
    IF devicePositionCount>maxDevicePos THEN
        FOR aDeviceId IN SELECT id FROM device_position WHERE device_position.deviceid=NEW.deviceid ORDER BY device_position.id ASC LIMIT devicePositionCount-maxDevicePos LOOP
            DELETE FROM device_position WHERE device_position.id=aDeviceId;
        END LOOP;       
    END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$trim_device_positions$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER trim_device_positions_trigger ON device_position; 
CREATE TRIGGER trim_device_positions_trigger AFTER INSERT ON device_position FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trim_device_positions();
```

Thanks for any wisdom coming my way :)

Comment: This is actually really hard to do reliably due to concurrency. There are also a number of existing answers on the topic here on SO; try to search some more. I'll see if I can find one of them too.

Comment: If you don't need to strictly limit to 50 entries, the best thing to do is a cron job / scheduled task that trims it to 50 entries periodically/lazily. In the mean time you just query it for the top 50 and ignore the rest.

Comment: Okay thanks so far! I'll look into existing solutions some more. I've tried to avoid it beforehand so that I had really learn it not copy it. The scheduled task seems interesting too. I'm uncertain as to how rigorous the trim should be but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: The main problem you'll face is the need to lock the whole table (or deal with `SERIALIZABLE` serialization failures and retries) if you're going to try to ensure you never go over 50.

Comment: @ Craig Ringer: Could you, by any chance, go into more detail about concurrency issues? Disregard it if there's plenty material anyhow but It would be nice to have it here beneath this particular expample ;)

Comment: Ah I see (somewhat). But I think it isn't that strict because usually I'm soley accessing the most recent one. The rest is just logging more or less.